# Intellij IDE font sizes ... Overflowing?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, fonts, ide

I know this isn't strictly programming related but I'm honestly at my wits end.
I've search all over, the problem is I don't really know how to describe this issue.

Basically what I want to know is how to fix this? The text seems to be offset or overflow out of the box. I've tried setting the font size in the settings and even tried various fonts.
[image: intellij overflow image]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you tried the "Override default fonts" option under the Appearance settings? Otherwise this may be OS related, which one are you using?

Comment: Hi yeah, I have tried that - Still no luck. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and I've installed the Gnome desktop on it.